# Micro service(eureka client) is not registering with eureka server / eureka server is not discovering the eureka client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

### eureka server set up

*pom.xml*

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

*main application class*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*application.properties*

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**eureka client set up**

*pom.xml*

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

*main application class*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8100
spring.application.name=currency-exchange-service

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761
```

I dont see the micro-service - currency-exchange-service registered with Eureka server in the eureka-server dashboard(http://localhost:8761)

1. Why is the eureka client not getting registered with eureka server?
2. Is @EnableDiscoveryClient same as @EnableEurekaClient ?

Comment: Check logs on client app, it it is not able to connect to server you might see logs.

Comment: @Yogesh I dont see any errors in the logs of the client app and dont see any anything related to eureka client in logs. But I see 'started eureka server' in the eureka-server logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created and tested with your config. The below two lines not required in discovery(eureka) client application.

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

Please use the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Actually `register-with-eureka : false` is stopping from registering with discovery(eureka) server, so remove it completely from client application.

Add the below line if the discovery(eureka) server port is other than 8761. For ex.,

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: I have added this property - register-with-eureka : false in eureka server project and not client project

Comment: Change the eureka client dependency `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks Alex. The root cause of the issue was because of incorrect dependency. I changed the dependency to spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client and it started working.

Comment: @Karthik I have done that but still Eureka client is not visible on eureka server while both applications are running without any error and I have used the dependency which is suggested here. What could be other possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

**@EnableDiscoveryClient**  annotation on the Client Application class will fix the issue.

This annotation is preferred and recommended over the older one - **@EnableEurekaClient**

@EnableEurekaClient is meant for the older version of Eureka server.

@EnableDiscoveryClient supports all available discovery services (including older version of eureka server)

Comment: @EnableDiscoveryClient is not available in spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client depedency of spring cloud version - Hoxton.SR1

Answer (score -1):

Since you have this actuator dependency, spring security dependency should have been added to your project by default. The possible cause of this registration failure is CSRF. Trying disabling CSRF by using below example code.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
    static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
```

Regarding point two in your question spring support many discovery service provider, for example consul, if you are using @EnableDiscoveryClient it will try to find the exact match in class path and use the same for discover service, on the other hand @EnableEurekaClient  is more specific to eureka discovery service, try to find eureka related dependencies in class path.